# Determine return type of C++ std algorithm function like count_if

Tags: c++

How can I determine the type of **std::** function like **std::count_if**?
Ideally, I'd like something like the following

```
using ret = std::invoke_result_t<std::count_if, const char*, const char*,
                                 std::function<bool(const char)>>;
```

But this does not work for multiple reasons.
I could get closer by:

```
using f = std::function<bool(const char)>;
using ret = std::invoke_result_t<std::count_if, const char*, const char*, f>;
```

But it is still not enough.

Error:

```
expected a type, got 'std::count_if'
```

Comment: Do you really need to know?  You can use `auto` so you don't have to know what the type actually is.

Comment: @NathanOliver - the full context is that there is a variable defined way at the beginning part of a func and it is populated later with std::count_if. I'd like to set the right type in the beginning of the func. this is a legacy code being refactored with modern C++. So I cannot use auto in this specific example (though I agree that auto should be used whenever possible). thx

Comment: strictly speaking `std::count_if` is not a function, thats the reason for the error. Its a function template. The functions you can get by instantiating the template have a return type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest way is just using decltype like this:

```
using type = decltype(
    std::count_if(
        std::declval<const char*>(),
        std::declval<const char*>(),
        std::function<bool(const char)>{}
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks. this worked. I thought the direction was to use result_of<> and similar. but this works as well :)

Comment: @Kobi `result_of` is deprecated in C++17, better use `invoke_result` if you must. IMHO decltype is almost always better choice since it never has problems with template functions

Comment: Are `declval`s usefull in this particular situation?